# Including form elements in a label_tag in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to enclose my text fields and other form elements in a label tag:

```
<label for="answer">Give it to me: <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer"/></label>
```

This way I can have the following CSS:

```
label {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And then the label and form element never split onto separate lines.  I know I can surround the whole label and form element with a `<span>` and use `white-space: nowrap;` on that, but I like having a label that covers everything.  At least sometimes.

Question is how to do this in Rails using their `label_tag` form helper.  Should I just include the other form element in the label_tag call?

```
<%= label_tag 'answer', "Give it to me: #{text_field_tag 'answer', @prev_answer, placeholder: 'Enter answer', class: 'special'}" %>
```

Comment: Just a note, SimpleForm is a really good gem for forms, it handles most of this already and provides easy config to customize it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the block syntax of `label_tag`. Something like this:

```
<%= label_tag 'answer' do %>
  Give it to me: <%= text_field_tag 'answer', @prev_answer %>
<% end %>
```

More info:
http://openmonkey.com/blog/2010/03/30/rails-label-helpers-with-blocks/
[Passing block to label helper in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088348/passing-block-to-label-helper-in-rails3)

Comment: The above didn't exactly work, the string you give `label_tag` is the `id` and you have to put the actual label between the `<% label_tag 'id' do %>` and `<%end%>`.