# How can I remove the default text from label helpers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a 5 star rating system in rails and am using fontawesome stars as my labels, so would like to remove the default label text "Ratings" which is popping up between the stars.

I am able to customize the text through the quotes, but when I leave a space as I have below, it doesn't produce a space as intended but reverts back to default behavior:

```
 <%= form_for order do |f| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :rating, "5", class: "star-rating__input" %>
      <%= f.label :rating, ' ', title: "Rocks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :rating, "4", class: "star-rating__input" %>
      <%= f.label :rating, ' ', title: "Pretty good", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :rating, "3", class: "star-rating__input" %>
      <%= f.label :rating, ' ', title: "Meh", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :rating, "2", class: "star-rating__input" %>
      <%= f.label :rating, ' ', title: "Kinda bad", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :rating, "1", class: "star-rating__input" %>
      <%= f.label :rating, ' ', title: "Sucks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <%= f.submit "Rate", class: "hidden btn btn-xs", id: "ratings-submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
<%= f.label :rating, '   ', title: "Rocks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>

<%= f.label :rating, '" "', title: "Rocks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>

<%= f.label :rating, "&nbsp;", title: "Rocks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>

<%= f.label :rating, "#{ }", title: "Rocks!", class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" %>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not really, I know how to enter customer text, what I don't know is how to remove it

Comment: Can you not write some HTML instead of Ruby between the radio buttons? Or maybe using an empty block ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088348/passing-block-to-label-helper-in-rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a block to enclose the label

```
<%= f.radio_button :rating, "5", class: "star-rating__input" %>
<%= f.label :rating do %>
  <i class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>
<%- end -%>
```

or you can use label_tag

```
<%= f.radio_button :rating, "5", class: "star-rating__input" %>
<%= label_tag :rating, '', class: "star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg"%>
```